# How to wrap certain sentences with <mark> tag after extracting them from paragraphs while keeping the same paragraph formatting for final output?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, spacy, sentence

I have an html file that contains only `<p>` and `<a>` tags. Like below -

```
<p>For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations. For example, if the current <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/conservative-leadership" title="">Conservative party leadership contest</a> proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method.</p> <p>In 2016, Theresa May’s<a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jun/30/conservative-leadership-race-who-are-the-five-candidates" title=""> rivals withdrew before the final round</a>. In previous applications of the rules it was the leader of the opposition being chosen, not a head of government. The system itself only dates back to 1998. Fine-tuning of the rules was completed by the 1922 Committee just three weeks ago. The process looks undemocratic and has no basis in ancient precedent.</p>
```

What I have to do is extract sentences with certain properties, for e.g: Sentences that contain `Britain` or `party`. And then mark the whole sentence with `<mark>` tags while keeping the paragraph formatting as it is.

To achieve this -

1. I first removed all tags to get just clean paragraphs with clean sentences.
2. Then I used [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) to extract sentences

```
with open('a.html') as f:
  given_text = f.read()    # Read from the file
#given_text = '' #copy paste the above html as string
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(given_text)
```

3. I finally iterate over sentences using `for sent in doc.sents` and use regex to know if the sentence should be marked or not.

But the trouble with this approach is that once I sanitize the text(removing all `<p>` and `<a>` tags) I lose all account of the individual paragraphs. So once I have marked the sentences with  tag, I get one single huge string.

How do I preserve the `<p>` formatting while still be able to iterate over sentences to flag them ?

The idea is to output exactly the way we got the input except with a few sentences highlighted.

Comment: Why not generating a new string? So before looping over `doc.sents` create a new string variable which is simple the empty string. If you loop over the sentences and recognize a sentence, which should be marked, you add `<mark>` to your new string, then the sentence and finally the closing tag. If it's not matching, you only add the sentence. Let me know if it helpes you. If not, please post your whole code and I will try to help you out.

Comment: Generating a new string would still face the exact same problem right? The main issue here is with Step 1, where I remove all the tags. That act itself makes me lose all formatting information. However that step is also crucial to be able to mark the sentences. Its become a catch-22 situation.

Comment: Oh I see, it's because spacy can't process the sentences if HTML-tags are still included?

Comment: Yeah, I mean I haven't tried it but I suppose it will make Spacy detect incorrect sentence boundaries. Moreover even if it works, it will just be a bad example. I don't want to take that risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

1. **Find sentences** with `britain` or `party`. I use the `re` module for regex formula.
2. **Replace** those sentences by adding `<mark>` add the **beginning** and **end** (of the sentence).

Here the code:

```
text = """<p> For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations. For example, if the current < a href = "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/conservative-leadership" title = "" > Conservative party leadership contest </a> proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method. < /p > <p > In 2016, Theresa May’s < a href = "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jun/30/conservative-leadership-race-who-are-the-five-candidates" title = "" > rivals withdrew before the final round < /a > . In previous applications of the rules it was the leader of the opposition being chosen, not a head of government. The system itself only dates back to 1998. Fine-tuning of the rules was completed by the 1922 Committee just three weeks ago. The process looks undemocratic and has no basis in ancient precedent. < /p >
"""



sentences_to_modify = re.findall(r"([^.]*?(party|Britain)[^.]*\.)", text)

for sentence in sentences_to_modify:
    text = text.replace(sentence[0], "<mark>"+sentence[0]+"<mark>")

print(text)
# <mark><p> For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations.<mark> For example, if the current < a href = "https://www.theguardian.<mark>com/politics/conservative-leadership" title = "" >
# Conservative party leadership contest < /a > proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method. < mark > < / p > <p > In 2016, Theresa May’s < a href = "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jun/30/conservative-leadership-race-who-are-the-five-candidates" title = "" > rivals withdrew before the final round < /a > . In previous applications of the
# rules it was the leader of the opposition being chosen, not a head of government. The system itself only dates back to 1998. Fine-tuning
# of the rules was completed by the 1922 Committee just three weeks ago. The process looks undemocratic and has no basis in ancient precedent. < /p >
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: So basically here we never actually split the sentences. We consider everything to be a giant blob of string and run regex... I suppose it will work for simple case as I described above. However lets say we do indeed have to perform some natural processing task, then i will have to clean and extract sentences from the paragraph. Any idea how to handle that situation?

Comment: Yes that will take a lot of resources, fully agree. Actually, what your pointing in my answer is how I detect the sentences. Here just by a point. By reading the comments in the question, if I have to do your process, I would define a structure in which I will keep all the `tags` with their position in the whole text. Then you can apply you different process (e.g. find sentences or others sentences process). Third, I will add the new tags `<mark>`. Finally rebuild the original text with tags from the structure previously defined (taking care of updating index position when you add new tags).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<p>For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations. For example, if the current <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/conservative-leadership" title="">Conservative party leadership contest</a> proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method.</p> <p>In 2016, Theresa May’s<a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jun/30/conservative-leadership-race-who-are-the-five-candidates" title=""> rivals withdrew before the final round</a>. In previous applications of the rules it was the leader of the opposition being chosen, not a head of government. The system itself only dates back to 1998. Fine-tuning of the rules was completed by the 1922 Committee just three weeks ago. The process looks undemocratic and has no basis in ancient precedent.</p>'''
src_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
dst_soup = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

WORDS_TO_LOOK_FOR = ['Britain', 'party']


def mark_if_needed(text):
    # can be improved using regex
    for word in WORDS_TO_LOOK_FOR:
        if word in text:
            return '<mark>' + text + '</mark>'
    return text


p_elements = src_soup.find_all('p')
for p in p_elements:
    a_elements = p.find_all('a')
    p.string = mark_if_needed(p.text)
    dst_soup.append(p)
    for a in a_elements:
        a.string = mark_if_needed(a.text)
        p.append(a)

print(dst_soup.prettify())
```

output

```
<p>
 &lt;mark&gt;For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations. For example, if the current Conservative party leadership contest proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method.&lt;/mark&gt;
 <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/conservative-leadership" title="">
  &lt;mark&gt;Conservative party leadership contest&lt;/mark&gt;
 </a>
</p>
<p>
 In 2016, Theresa May’s rivals withdrew before the final round. In previous applications of the rules it was the leader of the opposition being chosen, not a head of government. The system itself only dates back to 1998. Fine-tuning of the rules was completed by the 1922 Committee just three weeks ago. The process looks undemocratic and has no basis in ancient precedent.
 <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jun/30/conservative-leadership-race-who-are-the-five-candidates" title="">
  rivals withdrew before the final round
 </a>
</p>
```

Comment: This is really good. It gave me some idea. Let me implement that and then I will mark your solution as an answer.

Comment: @jar I am glad to help. Did you try to implement? Did it work for you?

Comment: There is one issue with this which is effectively the same with the other answer and what I had prevented me earlier....it will mark the whole paragraph even if there is only one sentence in that paragraph that qualifies to be highlighted. I just need to highlight specific lines, not the whole paragraph.

Comment: One more issue is that the `mark` tags actually get written as `&lt;mark&gt;` which doesn't end up highlighting the text.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of trying, I finally figured out how to do it. Following is a complete sample code for the same -

```
import re    
import spacy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

html_doc = '''<p>For a country that takes pride in the venerable stability of its democracy, Britain is strangely prone to constitutional improvisations. For example, if the current <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/conservative-leadership" title="">Conservative party leadership contest</a> proceeds as far as a ballot of party members, it will be the first time a prime minister is chosen by that method.</p> <p>This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit. This sentence should not be marked.</p> <p> This sentence should not be marked. This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit.</p> <p>This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit.</p> <p>This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit. This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit.</p> <p>This is an unmarked random sentence. This year, those leaders — Gov. Andrew Cuomo; the Senate majority leader, Andrea Stewart-Cousins; and the Assembly speaker, Carl Heastie — deserve significant credit. Another unmarked random sentnce.</p>'''

src_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser') 
dst_soup = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

word_re = "Britain"

def mark_if_needed(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for sent in doc.sents:
        check = re.search(word_re, sent.text)
        if check is None:
            yield (0, sent.text)
        else:
            yield (1, sent.text)

p_elements = src_soup.find_all('p')
for p in p_elements:
    s = BeautifulSoup()
    pp = BeautifulSoup()
    par = pp.new_tag('p')

    for sent in mark_if_needed(p.text):
        if sent[0] is 1:
            m = s.new_tag('mark') 
            m.append(sent[1])
            par.append(m)

        else:
            par.append(sent[1])

    dst_soup.append(par)

print(dst_soup.prettify())
html = dst_soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open("output.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```